# '' to '' meaning ? which one?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, grammar, word-usage, prepositions

What is the meaning of the preposition "to" in these sentences?

> The shoulder is proximal **to** the elbow.
>
> The ribs are lateral **to** the lungs.

***to :***

1. ***used for saying where someone or something is in relation to the position of another person or thing***
2. ***used as a function word to indicate addition, attachment, connection, belonging, possession, accompaniment, or response***

Which one ?

Comment: Both statements are describing spatial arrangement: (1) is the locative usage.

Answer (score 1):

The first definition of "to" would apply to the sentences in question. In these cases, the preposition "to" describes the position of one thing in relation to another. A person's shoulder is closer to the center of their body (proximal) than their elbow.